# Trying to move an item from one array to another in React state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, race-condition

I'm trying to learn react on my summer holidays. I'm recreating a card game called "Friday" and basically I need to move "cards" stored in arrays in state around. For example an array for a deck of cards and an array for a hand of cards but I'm running into race conditions when drawing cards too fast due to the async nature of set state. I finally have something I feel should work but it was adding two duplicates every time.
My current approach is a function that takes both arrays'  useSet setters like so:

```
function drawCard(fromSet, toSet) {
  fromSet( previous => {
    const[card, ...remainder] = previous;
    sendToTo(card);
    return [...remainder];
    });
  function sendToTo(card) {
    toSet(prev => [...prev, card]);
  }
}
```

However if I call this twice in quick succession and inspect the state afterwards I see the two cards are removed from the from array fine but the to array now has [card1, card2, card1, card2]

I've added a horrible fix for now but I'd rather do it right if possible. My fix is to change the toSet call to this:

```
toSet(prev => {
  if(prev.some(e => e === card))
    return [...prev];
  return [...prev, card];
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this sort of what you are looking for? Try clicking the button on this codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-glade-s7eut?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [deck, setDeck] = useState([]);
  const [hand, setHand] = useState([]);
  const [drawing, setDrawing] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const exampleDeck = [
      { cardNumber: 1, cardName: "Card1" },
      { cardNumber: 2, cardName: "Card2" },
      { cardNumber: 3, cardName: "Card3" },
      { cardNumber: 4, cardName: "Card4" },
      { cardNumber: 5, cardName: "Card5" }
    ];
    setDeck(exampleDeck);
  }, []);

  const drawCard = () => {
    if (deck.length > 0) {
      setDrawing(true);
      const topCard = deck[0];
      setHand((existingHand) => [...existingHand, topCard]);
      setDeck(
        deck.filter((deckCard) => deckCard.cardNumber !== topCard.cardNumber)
      );
      setDrawing(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Deck: </h4>
      {deck.length > 0 && deck.map((card) => <p>{card.cardName}</p>)}
      <h4>Hand: </h4>
      {hand.length > 0 && hand.map((card) => <p>{card.cardName}</p>)}
      <button onClick={drawCard} disabled={drawing}>
        Draw Card
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah almost. However instead of clicking a card in the deck you click a button that draws the top card of the deck. The issue is if I use deck[0] for this and update the two states respectively but the user hits the button again before the states are actually updated I end up drawing the same card twice and deleting the second one that should have been drawn.

Comment: @SimonFarrelly ok i just updated my answer + the codesandbox

Comment: That should do the job! Like a psuedo semaphore? Thanks! I'll try and read up more on the underlying workings of setState soon. I don't like the feeling of not knowing how something works as it makes you have to guess how to interact with it...

Comment: @SimonFarrelly are you referring to adding the disabled tag on the button? Yes, definitely add "loading" states while you are passing data around so you can prevent the user from clicking again before the operation is done. I get what you mean, I am the same, always gotta understand it from top to bottom

Comment: Yes so everything between setDrawing() is basically locked to one thread at a time (not sure the terminology in js). If I'm understanding the idea. Thanks again!